# How to pull item from hash array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Our rails code for pulling new content is as follows;

```
def self.update_from_feed_continuously(feed_url)
puts "I am running"
@all_feeds = Feed.all
for @feed in @all_feeds
  sleep 1.5
  xml = HTTParty.get(@feed.url).body
  @new_feed = Feedjira.parse(xml)
  @entry = @new_feed.entries.take(4)
  @items = Item.where("feed_id = ?", @feed.id)
  i = 0
  for @item in @items
    @new_item = @entry[i]
    @item.title = @new_item.title
    @item.description = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(@new_item.summary).css('p').text.strip.truncate(200)
    unless Nokogiri::HTML.parse(@new_item.content).css('img').nil?
      @item.image = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(@new_item.content).css('img').attr("src")
    end
    @item.url = @new_item.url
    @item.created_at = @new_item.published
    @item.save
    i = i + 1
  end
end
```

end

However, with most recent changes we get error on `title` not being defined anymore for `@item.title` and we know its because its an array or hash being returned by `@item` for `@items`.

We've used console to try and do `@item.title.first` or `@item[0].title` which worked, but using `@item[i].title` didn't

Comment: actually correction on that, we need to store `@new_item.title` into `@item.title`, however,  I can't figure out how, if `@item.title` and title is in a hash of @item.

Comment: Have you tried `@item[:title]` or `@item['title']`? BTW, this code is very non-rubyish. For enumerators, you would typically do something more like `Feed.all.each do |feed|`. Skip all that `i = 0` and `i = i + 1` stuff.

Comment: Hi @jvillian, yes, we've tried both of those and in console we can pull stuff, but in actual code its undefined. I also understand this is just a lot of extra in the code, it was developed by someone we let go few months back. The code did work few days ago running the queries so not sure whats up with it.

Comment: I feel like we need need more, specific information. What *exactly* is the class and attributes of `@item` when you are having the problem? Your code, upon casual observation, seems okay (even if non-rubyish).

Comment: `@item` or even `@items` are entries in database with columns like `title`, `description`, etc.. and so what is happening is for every `@item` we get the value of `@item.title` and simply updating that with whatever is in `@new_item.title` ... however, most recently `@item.title` is not defined, even though it is correct.

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @user1924165 this tipically is telling that the class it's not being loaded

Comment: you are iterating inside another block, ensure that when you iterate the i value have the number you need for a position

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara it does, we do the `i = i + 1` at the end of the block to make i next number in line or run time. We get that NoMethodError even though in console I'm able to pull @new_item.title and/or @item.title

Comment: Your question has the wrong title. Given the `NoMethodError`, your question should be "How to pull title from nil object?" And the answer is, "You can't, because it's a nil object." So, you question should *really* be, "Why is my object nil?" Some focused debugging should let you get to the bottom of that.

Comment: @jvillian looks like we got it fixed, one of the titles had a character that wasn't recognized. Removing that entry, made everything work again. I'm guessing we'll have to add `.strip` to our '@new_item.title` like `@new_item.title.strip`

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand to much about the need of use @feed. Instead, how about iterate using `each_with_index` method?

This way will give you the position in the array for every object.

**Example**

```
@all_feeds.each_with_index do |feed, feed_position_in_array_number|
  puts feed
  # will return the object
  puts feed_position_in_array_number
  # as example will return 4 that can help you for done something like @all_feeds[feed_position..] 
end
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index

Comment: While the pointer to the `each_with_index` method is good and valuable, it doesn't answer the OPs question.